# Same Letsencrypt for mailserver and domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, domain

I would like to know if it is possible and maybe recommendable to use only *one* (Letsencrypt) certiticate for encrypting traffic to a mailserver *and* to a website.

I have a domain `example.com` and issued Letsencrypt `certbot` successfully to fetch a certificate for the website at `example.com`.

My mail server is called   `mail.example.com`.

Can I use the same certificate in my mailserver configuration files for `postfix` and `dovecot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add more than one host name to a LE cert. It's not a problem. You just have to make sure that all affected systems get the new cert and are properly restarted/reloaded when it's renewal time.